# wmic temperature

Tags: wmic

How can I get temperature (for example CPU) of my 32bit windows 7 PC? (by using WMIC)

my results:

```
wmic temperature
No Instance(s) Available.
```

I run this command even with admin privileges, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 5):

You can just try :

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\WMI path MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature
```

Comment: I got an "Access denied" message in response to this.

Comment: @jcarmody : Have you try to run it as administrator ?

Comment: Worked for me, but how do you find that path?

Comment: Inspecting the "root/wmi" of the laptop. Under windows 10 you have to be in elevated mode (administrative privilege) to get informations.